# How can I test for browser support for an event

Tags: javascript, events, browser-feature-detection

Specifically, testing to see if `input[type=date]` fires the `input` event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By looking at [**this**](http://danielfriesen.name/blog/2010/02/16/html5-browser-maze-oninput-support/) website, I'd suggest you try

> Test B: Use setAttribute on an input to set an oninput and check to
>   see if node.oninput is a function
>   Test C: Use the w3 event api to create an input and fake a keypress
>   to see if oninput fires

Here is the JavaScript from Test C

```
function testC(){
    var input = document.createElement('input'),
        e = document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
    // set type for DATE
    input.setAttribute('type', 'date');
    e.initKeyEvent("keypress", true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 0, "e".charCodeAt(0));
    // use initKeyboardEvent for webkit
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.addEventListener("input", function(e) { alert('C Successful'); e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); }, false);
    input.focus();
    input.dispatchEvent(e);
    document.body.removeChild(input);
}
```

---

Edit: The test code is copied from [the test page](http://jsbin.com/efalu/7) with only a couple minor changes (position of var, type=date, alert). I ran it in chrome (after changing `initKeyEvent` to `initKeyboardEvent`) just now and it doesn't result in anything, however commenting out the `removeChild` line and doing it manually *does* result in success message. Not sure why the simulated event didn't invoke it so you'd need to look over this before applying it in your code.

Comment: Hm, so it seems like it's more complicated than just checking for `'oninput' in element`

Comment: `'oninput' in element` won't check if setting an `oninput` will actually do anything.

Comment: @PaulS do any browsers have an `oninput` which doesn't do anything? *edit* I read the article and see firefox is the culprit. But as the project I'm on only supports webkit I can get away with the simple existence test in this case

Answer (score 3):

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/UThQu/)

You can do this:

```
 var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
 var supported = 'oninput' in element;
```

Comment: great. I thought it was something like that but didn't realise you needed the `on` prefix

Comment: This won't check it actually fires.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood your comment, it doesn't fire the event. http://jsfiddle.net/hMTV8/

Comment: `.oninput` fires, http://jsfiddle.net/hMTV8/2/ , but your test doesn't check it fires. `.onchange` doesn't seem to fire.

Comment: It does not not fire on the check.

Comment: @Gabe look again at your fiddle, the check in your comment was on _onchange_. Look at the updated one in my comment (and also, this may be browser specific, I'm on Google Chrome 23.0.1271.64).